# MySQL - Parse Field

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(' ', name) LIKE 'Jor%'
LIMIT 15
```

It gives me all result that starts with "Jor":

> - Jorge
> - Jujuy
> - Jordania

But also I want this results:

> - Michael Jorckson
> - Fray Jordan
> - Etcetera Jor

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE name LIKE 'Jor%'
OR name LIKE '% Jor%'
LIMIT 15
```